# Load resource from classpath in inside jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-io, jar, resources

I am trying to pass a resource csv file to inside jar my Sprint Boot application is used.
I alway get a response that the file is not exist although the Resource parameter that the method get = ReactiveWebContext resource [src/main/resources/file.csv]

- In my project, I have the file located in src/main/resources/file.csv
- In application.properties, I define :

  ```
  file.csv.path=classpath*:file.csv
  ```
- In the config class :

  ```
  @Configuration
  @PropertySources({
  @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = 
   true)
  })
  public class BookConfiguration {
  }
  ```
- In the internal jar : Config class:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @Import({BoleroConfiguration.class})
  public class BoleroTestingInfraConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public FileProvider fileProvider(@Value("${file.csv.path}") Resource fileResource) throws 
  IOException {
      return new TestingProvider(fileResource);
  }
  ```
- The TestingProvider.class

  ```
  public class TestingProvider {

   private final Map<String, Set<Book>> idToBook;

   public TestingProvider(Resource fileResource) throws IOException {
     idToBook = getBooks(fileResource);
   }

   public Map<String, Set<Book>> getBooks(Resource fileResource) {
      if (fileResource == null || !fileResource.exists() ||
          !fileResource.getFile().exists() || !fileResource.getFile().isFile()) {
      return Optional.empty();
      }

   ....
   }
  }
  ```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1) The path you specified is not correct. It should be not *classpath*:file.csv*, but *classpath:file.csv*.

2) Normally in the JAR there will be no *src/main/resources/file.csv*. The file *src/main/resources/file.csv* exists only in the source code. The path *src/main/resources* corresponds to teh *root* level of the JAR. Thus the file *file.csv* will be at the *root* level of your JAR.

Comment: Fixed. Still not found the resource file.

Comment: Explain how you build the JAR. With Gradle? With Maven? Show corresponding config where you are creating the JAR.

Comment: I build the jar with maven.

Comment: Shortcut the variable to file.path solved the problem. Do you know why? Is there a limit?

Comment: No, the variable name cannot affect it. If it works, it means, there is something else in your code that you don't show.